# MVC Send back model properties after POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a Model that I send to the view in a GET method and is bounded successfully to `TextFor` and ListFor's

e.g.

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.MultiChoice, new MultiSelectList(Model.property, "Id", "Name"), new { multiple = "multiple", @class = "multiselect" })
```

When the user submits the form, the Model is successfully passed back to the POST action method with its properties.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult POST(Model quiz)
    {
      string Q1 = quiz.Q1 // = will equal what the user has put in. good

      return View("Quiz", quiz);
    }
```

However, when the Model (quiz) is returned to the view, the properties inside the quiz model are NULL, how do I retain the properties that come through to the POST method?

** Edit **

The GET Method

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Quiz()
    {
        try
        {
            Quiz quiz = new Quiz();

            // Of course, I could do this in the constructor of the model..
            InitialiseQuiz(Quiz);

            return View("Quiz", quiz");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: I see contradiction between 'When the user submits the form, the Model is **successfully passed back to the POST action method with its properties**' and 'However, when the Model (quiz) is returned to the view, the properties inside the quiz model are **NULL**'

Comment: How does your GET method looks like ? And your view ?

Comment: the quiz view is typed for Model?

Comment: Sorry @TomasVoracek - will clarify. View -> controller - Model values OK. Controller -> view (after post) - empty

Comment: @AlexanderBrevig - Have updated with my GET method, what do you need to see in my view? As its pretty large!

Comment: Is there a difference between Quiz and quiz views?

Comment: @Recipe - sorry a typo

Comment: do you have code in your view? and you definitly checked the quiz object in your post with the debugger?

Comment: Another thing: in the Get, you create a Quiz object, but the input parameter of the POST method is Model. Also wondering what the model in your view is?

Comment: Is the model retaining ANY data or just some of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well, when you do this:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.MultiChoice, new MultiSelectList(Model.property, "Id", "Name"))
```

the Razor will create a `<select>` tag with `x.MultiChoice` values as selected options. BUT, nowhere will be persisted the `Model.property` values (as it may be a collection, right?).

So, when you do the POST, you will only send the `x.MultiChoice` value back to the server, and the `Model.property` collection will be missed.

Knowing that, you just need to fill this property with the collection again during the POST action, like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult POST(Model quiz)
{
    // some code here

    quiz.property = new CollectionOfSomething();
    return View("Quiz", quiz);
}
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: That is what I am currently doing - is this is the correct way of doing it then I ma happy. the problem was that when I need to bind the collection again, I need to use EF which means going to the database or using local which is slow, but I work around it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The modelbinder news up an instance of that class with whatever POST data it has. Anything that's null has no posted data. The easiest way to make it not be null, then, is to create an HTML input for that property so that something is posted for it.

However, in situations where you're dealing with existing data, it's preferable to only post what you need to post, and then lookup the original object again in order to map the original property values back onto the version that was passed into your action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Quiz(int id, Quiz model)
{
    var quiz = db.Quizzes.Find(id);
    // assuming `Foo` was a property that was not posted
    model.Foo = quiz.Foo

    ...
}
```